# How to create regex from any letter to a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this: `http://someurl.com?someparameter=dhws6sd6cvg` and i would like to mach part from first letter to '=' with javascript regex. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern should match until `=`:

```
.+?=
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a group which will match all the words starting from the beginning till the `=`. You can then access the regex group as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex).

Something like: `^(.*?)=` Should yield the following group value: `http://someurl.com?someparameter`. If you would like to include the `=`, then, just do as follows: `^(.*?=)`

Answer (score 2):

Up front: If you're parsing URLs, you might want to use one of the existing URL parsers or [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/).

The beginning of a string is denoted by `^` so your RegEx could look like `^([^=]+)`. This matches everything but `=` from the beginning of the string. If you only want the part after the ?, try `\?([^=]+)`. Note that you'll only get the very first parameter this way.

Have a look at MDN explaining [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 2):

The use of `.*` will cause the regex to back track and use of `()` will create a backreference. So we can use this to capture the given string `^[^=]+=`