# Regexp - from first character to & character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this: `http://someurl.com?test&lettersg` and I would like to mach part from first letter to `&` (without `&`, this part only: `http://someurl.com?test`).

Comment: What have you tried? This seems to be a very straightforward task which does not even require regular expressions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to grab substring before a specified character jquery or javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133102/how-to-grab-substring-before-a-specified-character-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Should be easy if you've solved your previous problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392940/how-to-create-regex-from-any-letter-to-a-specific-character/9393022#9393022

... an almost-exact copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var match = /^[^&]*/.exec("http://someurl.com?test&lettersg")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If its the code you want, look at the source of [this JQuery Plugin (URL Parser)](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser). Or you can just go ahead and use the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For URL manipulation I suggest using [URI.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/).

Your problem can be solved with and without RegExp:

```
var string = "http://someurl.com?test&lettersg";
console.log(string.match(/^[^&]+/)[0]);
console.log(string.substring(0, string.indexOf('&')));
```